# How do I find the number of cores needed for CPU if I know the expected transactions per second?

Tags: hardware

We are in a scenario where we have a rough idea regarding the expected number of transactions per second in the database server. We don't have the actual (custom built) software in hand.

When planning for hardware, how do I determine the number of cores for the CPU for the server in which the software will be housed?

Is there any guide or best practices from which I can determine the number of cores for the CPU for the latest processor in use right now?

Comment: Is this for a specific database product, or a question in general?

Comment: There are going to be around thirty different products to be housed in different physical servers. All are under development. So, right now you need to consider the question to be general.

Comment: The number of transaction does not say much. There are transactions which need a lot of CPU and there are those which need almost none. Load testing would be the way to go. Anyone who can custom build you a solution should be able to provide you with a load test (and should probably have that planned for a new system anyways, because sometimes the blocker is not the database but the system)

Answer (score 2):

For the larger DB vendors & hardware vendors there will be reference architectures. These state -- very roughly -- some pre-configured set of hardware to address a given workload. If you read through a few of those you may be able to find one that more-or-less matches what you're thinking about.

However ... no two workloads are quite the same. A transaction that does a single-row key look-up will have very different hardware requirements to one that executes an ML algorithms to one that aggregates a terabyte of data warehouse.